# How to receive the final selected item in a drop down list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a table in a form with several courses in it and each of the courses has a select menu to select the duration of the course. Bellow the form containing this table, I have another form with a text area named "Selected Courses & Duration" that automatically fetches the name of courses that the user set the duration for (e.g. Course A for 1 Month, Course B for 3 Months, etc.).

The problem with the approach that I'm using is every time the user changes his mind after selecting the first duration, then the "Selected Courses..." form field is showing multiple durations for the same courses. For example, if the user first selected "for 1 Month" from the select menu of Course A, and then later changed his mind and selected "for 3 Months" from the select menu of Course A, the "Selected Courses and Duration" form field will have two entries for the same course "Course A":

*Selected Courses and Duration*

Course A for 1 Month
Course A for 3 Months

While I want only one final selected value of each course showing up in this form field so no matter how many times the user changes his mind, the "Selected Courses ..." form field always fetches only the final selected duration.

Here's the HTML code that I'm using for the first and second forms:

```
<form id="course-selector" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="course-a-heading">
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="course-name">Course A</td>
                <td class="duration">
                    <select name="course-a" id="course-a">
                        <option value="">None</option>                                                                          
                        <option value="35">1 Month</option>                                                                         
                        <option value="72">3 Months</option>                                                                            
                        <option value="125">6 Months</option>                                                                           
                        <option value="230">12 Months</option>                                                                          
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="total">SFr. <span id="courseatotal" data-format="SFr. 0,0[.]00" data-formula="$coursea"></span>.--</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="course-name">Course B</td>
                <td class="duration">
                    <select name="course-b" id="course-b">
                        <option value="">None</option>                                                                          
                        <option value="35">1 Month</option>                                                                         
                        <option value="72">3 Months</option>                                                                            
                        <option value="125">6 Months</option>                                                                           
                        <option value="230">12 Months</option>                                                                          
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="total">SFr. <span id="coursebtotal" data-format="SFr. 0,0[.]00" data-formula="$courseb"></span>.--</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="vfb-132" id="vfb-132" class="vfb-textarea  vfb-medium   sel-courses" readonly="">No course selected</textarea>
</form>
```

And here is the jQuery code that inserts courses with selected durations in the text area (#vfb-132) of the second form:

```
var output = "";
$("select").on('change', function() {
    var rselect, duration;

    duration = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
    rselect = $(this).closest('tr');

    rselect.find('.course-name').each(function(){
        output += $(this).html() + " for " + duration + "\n";

        $("#vfb-132").val(output);
    });
});
```

I've tried to search this site as well as Google and a few other places but couldn't come up with a solution. Please help!

Thanks a lot!

Sincerely,
Avinash

Comment: set the text area value to null every time the select function is triggered. `$("select").on('change', function() {  $("#vfb-132").val("");
    var rselect, duration; //remaining code`

Comment: is your select id unique?

Comment: Hi Cerlin, yes, all the select IDs are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fascinating problem to work with.  I added the following to your `.find` function:

```
var courseName = $(this).html();
var exists = output.indexOf(courseName) > -1;
if (exists)
{
    var pattern = courseName + " .*\n";
    pattern = new RegExp(pattern);
    var arr = output.split(output.match(pattern));
    arr[arr.indexOf("")] = courseName + " for " + duration + "\n";
    output = arr.join("");
    $("#vfb-132").val(output);
    return;
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8h8nv403/).  Cheers!

EDIT:

If the names of all the items are not going to be unique, the best solution is probably not to mess with regex matching.  Instead, just reconstruct the entire text each time an option is changed, like so:

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
    var output = "";
    $('.duration').each(function() {
        var duration = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
        if (duration.trim() == "None") return;

        var courseName = $(this).prev().html();
        output += courseName + " for " + duration + "\n";
    });
    $("#vfb-132").val(output);
});
```

This is much shorter code anyway, and much less error-prone.  Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8h8nv403/6/) for it.

Comment: What a rock solid solution! Thanks a lot, bowheart! You're amazing!

Comment: Hey bowheart, your solution works pretty much with everything, except when course name has a "+" in it. For example, if the course is a pack of two courses with the name "Course A + Course B", only the first selected value is added to the text area and then no matter how many times I select different duration, it doesn't update anything for the course with a "+" in its name. Could you please help me out with this? What's causing this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that would probably be the regex trying to use the '+' as part of the syntax instead of matching it with the rest of the string.  And I didn't know there would be duplicate names amongst the items.  My solution was based on all rows being unique.  However, if you added something in the text of the double-course options, there is a work-around.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8h8nv403/3/

Comment: @AvinashSingh I've added an EDIT section to my answer with a solution that can handle duplicates.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, bowheart! The edited solution also took care of an oversight in the previous code that when a user was selecting "None" after first having selected a duration, then the "None" was also being added to the output and I love the way the edited version is much shorter than the previous solution! 

Once again, thanks a lot! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that will help you
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gqac6omk/1/)

```
<form id="course-selector" onsubmit="return false;">
<table class="table">
<tbody>
  <tr class="course-a-heading">
    <th>Course Name</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
                <td id="course-name-A">Course A</td>
                <td class="duration">
                    <select name="course-a" id="course-a">
                        <option value="">None</option>                                                                          
                        <option value="35">1 Month</option>                                                                         
                        <option value="72">3 Months</option>                                                                            
                        <option value="125">6 Months</option>                                                                           
                        <option value="230">12 Months</option>                                                                          
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="total">SFr. <span id="courseatotal" data-format="SFr. 0,0[.]00" data-formula="$coursea"></span>.--</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
                <td id="course-name-B">Course B</td>
                <td class="duration">
                    <select name="course-a" id="course-B">
                        <option value="">None</option>                                                                          
                        <option value="35">1 Month</option>                                                                         
                        <option value="72">3 Months</option>                                                                            
                        <option value="125">6 Months</option>                                                                           
                        <option value="230">12 Months</option>                                                                          
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="total">SFr. <span id="courseatotal" data-format="SFr. 0,0[.]00" data-formula="$coursea"></span>.--</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>


<form method="post">
<textarea name="vfb-132" id="vfb-132" class="vfb-textarea  vfb-medium   sel-courses" readonly="">No course selected</textarea>
</form>
```

js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#course-a,#course-B').on('change', function(){
            $('#vfb-132').val();

            var courseNameA = $('#course-name-A').text();
            var durationA = $('#course-a').find('option:selected').text();
            var outputcourseA = courseNameA +' FOR '+ durationA + ',';
            if(durationA == 'None'){
                outputcourseA = "";
            }
             var courseNameB = $('#course-name-B').text();
            var durationB = $('#course-B').find('option:selected').text();
             var outputcourseB = courseNameB +' FOR '+ durationB + ',';
            if(durationB == 'None'){
                outputcourseB = '';
            }
            $('#vfb-132').val(outputcourseA + outputcourseB );
            if($('#vfb-132').val() == ""){
               $('#vfb-132').val('No course selected'); 
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mohamed-Yousef! Your answer was pretty close but I think bowheart's solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = "";
        $("#course-a").on('change', function () {
            var rselect, duration;
            $("#vfb-132").val("");
            output = "";
            duration = "";
            duration = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
            rselect = $(this).closest('tr');
            rselect.find('.course-name').each(function () {
                output += $(this).html() + " for " + duration + "\n";
                if ($("#course-b").val() != '0') {
                    output += $(this).html() + " for " + $("#course-b").find("option:selected").text() + "\n";
                }
                $("#vfb-132").val(output);
            });
        });

        $("#course-b").on('change', function () {
            var rselect, duration;
            output = "";
            duration = "";
            $("#vfb-132").val("");
            duration = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
            rselect = $(this).closest('tr');
            rselect.find('.course-name').each(function () {
                if ($("#course-a").val() != '0') {
                    output += $(this).html() + " for " + $("#course-a").find("option:selected").text() + "\n";
                }
                output += $(this).html() + " for " + duration + "\n";

                $("#vfb-132").val(output);
            });
        });
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzozur3v/)

Comment: Hi Aditya, Thanks for your answer but that doesn't help. Please also note that as I wrote in my question, there are several courses in that table, not only one so I'm concatenating outputs for each selected course and then inserting it in the text area.

Comment: updated answer. it can further be simplified by creating a common class for the select and referencing the respective courses by attribute id.